# How to use Rails detect in Rails on incoming Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So recently I was helped out finding a way of using `detect` in rails to grab a url from text... however that would come very useful for me also in a controller if its possible.

My controller grabs some info and created a new entry into the DB based on incoming params, looks something like this;

```
    @received_msg = Message.create(:content => params[:Text], :user_id => user.id, :status => 'new')
```

Now, I was hoping that using `detect` in my controller on the create action, I could search the `:content` for specific text or symbol and allow my users to define few things in content but I would assign that to a different column. I'm sure this isn't clear so let me show by example.

EXAMPLE:

Let's say my user send a message with content like so;

```
   "Hey there, you should check this type of website out and make sure that its good to go"
```

Now, I'm assigning a USER_ID for the user that submitted this message, but the original owner could be someone else before the user submitted it. So I thought I would allow my user_id to enter `@John` into their message, meaning the original owner of the message was `JOHN`.. the new message would look something like this;

```
   "Hey there, you should check this type of website out and make sure that its good to go @John"
```

Now in my controller when that message is created as a record, I'd like to take `JOHN` and assign it to the column `username` for example; I thought something like this would work but its giving me error `.detect` undefined..

```
   @received_msg = Message.create(:content => params[:Text], :user_id => user.id, :status => 'new', :username => (params[:Text].detect {|original_sender| original_sender.start_with? "@"))
```

Maybe too many brackets?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `}` at the end

```
@received_msg = Message.create(:content => params[:Text], :user_id => user.id, :status => 'new', :username => (params[:Text].detect {|original_sender| original_sender.start_with? "@"}))
```

you can also use the below for what you want

```
@received_msg = Message.create(:content => params[:Text], :user_id => user.id, :status => 'new', :username => params[:Text].split.find{|w| w.start_with?("@")})
```

Comment: that just returns `undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the params right? is it `params[:Text]` or `params[:text]` ?

Comment: it's `params[:Text]` for sure... works fine without `.split` or `.find`

Comment: yes. because if you access any non existing symbol from `params`, it would return `nil`. `eg: params[:random] => nil`

Comment: but it does exist... :) because I'm using it for `:content => params[:Text]` and it does get the message text and puts it into `:content`